# Kafka connect with mysql custom query

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have done incremental data sync with help of kafka connect.
Now i want to achieve same with custom query. But I am getting error.

My config file is

```
name=mysql-whitelist-timestamp-source
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector 
tasks.max=1 
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/demouser=root&password=root 
query=select name from students3 where marks = 10 
mode=timestamp table.whitelist=students3 
timestamp.column.name=timestamp 
topic.prefix=test-mysql-jdbc-
```

And getting below error:

> ERROR WorkerConnector{id=mysql-whitelist-timestamp-source} Error while
>   starting connector
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:119)
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: query may not be
>   combined with whole-table copying settings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We shouldn't use the tag **table.whitelist** with the custom query. see the full [explanation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confluent-platform/TtuPKb5xZIk).